# How to redirect 'file url' to 'post url' i.e. in attachment.php

Tags: attachments, redirect, images

I've just started using the attachment.php template on my site.  What I'd like to do is redirect all images in posts that used 'file url' to 'post url' and my new attachment.php template.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

EB

Comment: It might help to provide your code for the attachment.php.

Comment: For clarity(as i think i follow the question), Everton is asking how he can update all posts that currently reference an attach in their content and point to the file url, and replace those URLs with the individual attachments URL. Something you'll likely only get done with custom SQL and regex...(there's no quick one liner for this)..

Answer (score 1):

Link to the image file using [`wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link):

- `$id` is the attachment ID, which, if using `attachment.php`, will simply be `$post->ID`
- `$size` is the image size, e.g. `full`, `large`, `medium`, `thumbnail`
- **`$permalink` determines whether a link to the *file* or *post* is returned. Use `false` (which is the default) to link to the *file***
- `$icon` refers to a mime-type icon. Leave `false`, which is default
- `$text` displays a text link. Leave `false`, which is default

Comment: thanks for the answer.  How and where do I add this code so that old posts linking to images via the file url, will 'redirect' to the post url for the image?

Comment: It would go in the Loop, and replace the current code, which, I'm guessing is simply `the_content()`, in `attachment.php`

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look at the solution on the WordPress Support Forum:**
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-attachment-page-to-post-page-how-to

Comment: Thanks, but this goes the wrong way around - post url 2 file url, not file url 2 post url